# Error using Java API for Google geocoder

Tags: google-geocoder, geocode, google-geocoding-api, java

I need to geocode address in Java but below code throws  UnknownHostException. The link I referred is http://code.google.com/p/geocoder-java/

```
final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();
GeocoderRequest geocoderRequest = new GeocoderRequestBuilder().setAddress("Paris,France").setLanguage("en").getGeocoderRequest();
GeocodeResponse geocoderResponse = geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest);


Mar 5, 2014 2:39:10 PM com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder geocode
SEVERE: maps.googleapis.com
java.net.UnknownHostException: maps.googleapis.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:860)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:726)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1049)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder.request(Geocoder.java:68)
at com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder.geocode(Geocoder.java:59)
```

***Also can I use this class without Google Maps?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was proxy issue for me. So I just set the proxy and it worked for me.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myproxy.domain.com"); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "myport");
```